ExecutionContext's implementation in Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker?
I was upgrading my Azure Function V1 written in net461 to Azure Functions V4 in net48 while doing there is some ExecutionContext present in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs which is being used herestring appDirectoryPath = context.FunctionDirectory; please help me find an implementation which I can use with Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker
Old .csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="3.4.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
   <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="SSH.NET" Version="2016.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.2" />
 </ItemGroup>

New .csproj
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>


Can you share the .csproj file?

Do you want to know this path

Use Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)); to get the path which is C:\home\site\wwwroot

Isolated function does have ExecutionContext but it doesn't have FunctionDirectory property in it, refer this MS Doc.
If you would like to access the function location, you can use Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) . By using this , I am able to get the expected function location.
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace _78372475
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            _logger.LogInformation("Function Path: {Path}", path);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>_78372475</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output-

References:-
Access FunctionAppDirectory in .NET 5 Azure Function - Stack Overflow.
